# When does X6-88 become available as a companion?

Tags: fallout-4

According to the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/X6-88) X6-88 becomes available as a companion "(...)a short while after the incident is resolved(...)" where I presume the incident is the quest [Synth Retention](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Synth_Retention). However I've done the quest some time ago (several in-game weeks) and yet when I speak to X6-88 there is no dialog. I'm currently on the first part of [The Battle of Bunker Hill](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Battle_of_Bunker_Hill) and have no plans to continue on this quest line until I've completed more quests for all the factions.

Answer (score 1):

Basically after completing the mission Synth Retention, Father informs you that he has acquired some accommodation for you and that you should go and check it out. X6-88 is waiting outside your accommodation and you can speak to him and ask him to follow you from that point.

Comment: I did not specifically speak to X6-88 when I got my quarters, however he greeted me when I entered them. Now he mostly hangs out in the Synth Retention area of the Institute.

Comment: If your game bugs out and he's not there, fast travel to Libertalia and start heading up. The quest should complete and the next quest "Mankind, Redefined" should trigger.

Comment: @Ohnana I tried this, did not work. Went all the way back up the ship in Lebertalia. Through the captain's quarters and up to the top. Mankind Redefined is also not the quest that follows Synth Retention. As I stated in my original question I'm on the start of the quest The Battle of Bunker Hill which is in between Synth Retention and Mankind Redefined.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should read the wiki before pulling things out of my spincter :) I meant the bunker hill quest, but it's strange that the quest didn't trigger. I'd use setStage to fix it, because there aren't any scripted events that it triggers.